# Animate scroll not working in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div  style="z-index: 1;" class="visible-xs visible-sm"><a href="index.html"><img id="bizviz_logos" src="resources/images/logoaccses.png"  class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
             <ul id="menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">


<li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="menu_scroll" data-toggle="dropdown">Support <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="downloadtrailversion.html">Download </a></li>
            <li><a href="blogs.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="whitepaper.html">Papers</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="documentation.html">Document</a></li>
            <li><a href="licenseassistance.html">License</a></li>
            <li><a href="submitproblem.html">Problem</a></li>
            <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
            <li><a href="faq.html" class="dropdown-toggle">FAQ</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

             </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click','#menu_scroll',function(e){
                event.preventDefault();

                $('.navbar-collapse.in').animate({scrollTop: 100}, 250);

})
```

As in above am using jquery for scroll.when i click a menu item(bootstrap mobile - toggle button) in my header of website...its working fine in chrome but in firefox its not working(scroll is not happening).any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Can you give us a fiddle? You're binding to '#menu_scroll' but I can't see an element with that id in your html. Your html doesn't seem to have a `.navbar-collapse.in` either.

Comment: HAd updated my code @artm

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        // hide #back-top first
        $("#back-top").hide();

        // fade in #back-top
        $(function () {
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                    $('#back-top').fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $('#back-top').fadeOut();
                }
            });

            // scroll body to 0px on click
            $('#topanimated a').click(function () {
                $('body,html').animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 800);
                return false;
            });
        });

    });
```

Set This ID in The Button id="back-top"